# Use web.config to configure default Report Server

Tags: configuration, reporting-services

I'm developing an app that will manage users' access to various SSRS reports. Most of the report will exist on a default Report Server, but we want to allow for growth to other Report Servers.

Access is controlled by a SQL Server 2008 R2 db, which includes the Report Path. Currently, if the report path begins with "/", we use the localhost/reportserver. Otherwise, if the path begins with "http://", I parse out the remoter reportserver and report path.

What I want to do is configure the default report server in web.config (it won't, of course, be localhost). But, I'm unable to find anything that will help me do this.

Any ideas will be most graciously accepted.

Thanks in advance,
Michell

Comment: You mean you'd like to set a variable in .net which will hold your default path to reportserver, or you want to actually 'configure' the report server?

Comment: @Sam Not sure if this will work as a comment answer -- I'm still very new to the whole Stack Overflow environment. At any rate, I'm trying to set a default server location in the web.config file that will override SSRS's default of "localhost".

Answer (score 0):

Would an environment variable work for that?  Set it in the webconfig and retrieve in your code.  Seems too simple, so maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: I think you may be on the right track. My question is where in the web.config file should such an environment variable be declared. That is, using which tag?